# When should user-select:contain be used?

Tags: css

I 'm reading at the documentation of [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) and I cannot figure out where should `contain` value be used.

> contain
> Enables selection to start within the element; however, the selection will be contained by the bounds of that element.

I am looking for a practical example to demonstrate its usage. What is the difference to not adding `user-select` at all?

Comment: If you are testing in most browsers, there is no difference. `contain` is [not supported by any modern browser](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_user-select_contain).

Comment: @DBS yes but [polyfills](https://github.com/github/user-select-contain-polyfill) exist. Plus the value is not marked as `experimental`.